# Speed up SELECT query with JOIN from table with 2.2M rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, query, query-performance

There are two tables in PostgreSQL:

```
//has 2.2 millions rows 
create table account (
    account_id text primary key,
    email text not null,
    created_at timestamp not null
);

//has 1.8 millions rows
create table account_intercom (
    account_id text primary key references account(account_id),
    intercom_id text not null
);
```

It's easy to notice ~400k rows difference between these tables.
I want to select these 400k `account_id` and perform some operations with them in order to eliminate this "gap".

I tried this query:

```
SELECT account_id, email
  FROM
    account NATURAL LEFT JOIN
    account_intercom
  WHERE intercom_id IS NULL;
```

But it runs extremely slow.

What is the way to speed up this query?

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                
---------------------------------------------------
 Hash Left Join  (cost=75252.40..207091.91 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=30056.787..87284.881 rows=417195 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (account.account_id = account_intercom.account_id)
   Filter: (account_intercom.intercom_id IS NULL)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1799858
   ->  Seq Scan on account  (cost=0.00..47840.67 rows=2221867 width=46) (actual time=0.010..13484.228 rows=2217053 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=36919.51..36919.51 rows=1800551 width=48) (actual time=30018.683..30018.683 rows=1799858 loops=1)
         Buckets: 65536  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 2722kB
         ->  Seq Scan on account_intercom  (cost=0.00..36919.51 rows=1800551 width=48) (actual time=0.008..9801.883 rows=1799858 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.333 ms
 Execution time: 88794.797 ms
```

Comment: You should **never** use `NATURAL JOINS`

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL, and on what hardware?  I can run this query in less than 5 seconds on a low-end laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like this with a `NOT EXISTS` statement

```
SELECT account_id, email
FROM account AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM account_intercom AS i
  WHERE a.account_id = i.account_id
);
```

Make sure your stats are uptodate and your table clean,

```
VACUUM FULL account;
VACUUM FULL account_intercom;
```

Paste the updated `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: Be careful with `VACUUM FULL` - depending on the size of your tables it will lock for all operations.